# how to group radio buttons based on same class instead of same name

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

Is there a way to group the set of radio buttons that share the same class.

I want to be able to be able to check the radio button from each set.

Currently it allows me to check only one radio button (as I know because of same name)

Is there a JQuery way either ?

Example:

**SET A**

```
<input type="radio" name="item[]" class="a" value="1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="item[]" class="a" value="2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="item[]" class="a" value="3"><br>
<input type="radio" name="item[]" class="a" value="4"><br>
```

**SET B**

```
<input type="radio" name="item[]" class="b" value="5"><br>
<input type="radio" name="item[]" class="b" value="6"><br>
<input type="radio" name="item[]" class="b" value="7"><br>
<input type="radio" name="item[]" class="b" value="8"><br>
```

Comment: Why can you not name the two sets differently? Do you only want 1 of all of them to be selectable?

Comment: I appreciate quick answer. Well the radio buttons are being generated dynamically with php loop. I can not name them differently.

Comment: Any JavaScript solution will have to alter their names to achieve that. If the PHP on the back end is supposed to save the values, it's probably relying on field names. So be aware that a client-side only change may break something on the server side.

Comment: @gdoron I tried but it is not working with body tag either. which jquery version did you use at demo ? in fact it broken other jquery code too.

Comment: @smartpctech. It has to be **1.7+**

Comment: @gdoron It worked now. but it didn't solve my problem because it is again giving it a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so you are trying to have multiple array entries, but using 1 array.

Since html interprets them as having the same name, you will have to add the numbers into the array key yourself.

So something like this should work.

```
<input type="radio" name="item[0]" class="a" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="item[0]" class="a" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="item[0]" class="a" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="item[0]" class="a" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="item[0]" class="a" value="5" />

<input type="radio" name="item[1]" class="b" value="6" />
<input type="radio" name="item[1]" class="b" value="7" />
<input type="radio" name="item[1]" class="b" value="8" />
<input type="radio" name="item[1]" class="b" value="9" />
<input type="radio" name="item[1]" class="b" value="10" />
```

Comment: actually i need to loop through item[] array like  < ?php foreach($_POST['item'] as $items){ echo $item; }.

Comment: **Thanks** for your best answer, It saved me alot

Comment: No problemo. Always glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#container').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
    this.name = this.className;
});​
```

This <s>should</s> solves it.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/r9GMM/4)

Comment: on demo it worked but as i tested it on my local machine with following code it didn't work. <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#container').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
    this.name = this.className;
});​

});
</script>

Comment: @smartpctech. Do you have a `container` id in you page...? change it to `body` and test it again: `$('body').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
    this.name = this.className;
});​`

Comment: yes i had <div id="container"> and i tried with body element. did not work. which jquery version did you use in demo site.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not name the sets differently?

SET A

```
< input type="radio" name="item1[]" class="a" value="1">
< input type="radio" name="item1[]" class="a" value="2">
< input type="radio" name="item1[]" class="a" value="3">
< input type="radio" name="item1[]" class="a" value="4">
```

SET B

```
< input type="radio" name="item2[]" class="b" value="5">
< input type="radio" name="item2[]" class="b" value="6">
< input type="radio" name="item2[]" class="b" value="7">
< input type="radio" name="item2[]" class="b" value="8">
```

Comment: is there a java script way to group the radio buttons based on same class ?